# Jquery change CSS color of several label by name passing through JSON

Tags: jquery, css, json, label

I have a simple JSON array containing label names with problems, which is created by php after form validation. I am hoping to have a universal Jquery function where I could pass on the list of labels, run a loop (each?) and change the colour of all present in the list?

for example:

```
  var json = ["email", "password"];
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('json').each(function () {
         $(this).css("color", "red");
     });
 });

 <label for="email"> Email </label> 
 <label for="password"> Password </label>
```

I am at loss in the loop and calling the labels, I have tried few options but not with much luck, hopefully one of you can help me out and point me in the right direction? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the labels using [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector as shown below:

```js
var json = ["email", "password"];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each(json,function (index,value) {
     $("label[for='"+value+"']").css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="email"> Email </label> 
<label for="password"> Password </label>
```

*Side note: It's safer to include quotes around the attribute value, otherwise [it won't work](http://jsfiddle.net/77g2e5w5/2/) with values having more than one word*

Comment: @Anx..yes as mentioned by Tj use quotes around the attribute value if you have more then one word but in your case you can leave using single quotes because you have only one word.. ...

Answer (score 1):

Modify your **foreach loop** as shown :

```
$.each(json,function(index,value){
   $("label[for='" + value + "']").css('color','red')
});
```

**EDIT :-**

Now your complete code will look like as shown below :

```js
var json = ["email", "password"];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each(json,function (index,value) {
     $("label[for='" + value + "']").css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <label for="email"> Email </label> 
 <label for="password"> Password </label>
```

If you want to target other DOM elements with attribute only then try this:

```js
var json = ["email", "password","email id"];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each(json,function (index,value) {
     $("[for='" + value + "']").css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="email"> Email </label> 
<label for="password"> Password </label>

<span for="email id"> Email id </label>
```